# How to make Android properly display screen density based Images?

Tags: android, screen, screen-density

I have an Android app with five different screen density based `drawable\` images.

```
drawable-hdpi
drawable-mdpi
drawable-xhdpi
drawable-xxhdpi
drawable-xxxhdpi
```

When I run the app on a LG3 it displays *mdpi* sized images. Which works/fits perfectly. But when I run the app on a kindle fire (much much larger screen), it still displays *mdpi* images. Which I thought (and designed the app) to work with *hdpi* sized images for the kindle. After some research I found the type of kindle fire I have uses *mdpi* screen density also. How can I make this work since the kindle is **SO** much larger in screen size? Did I do something wrong. Is the kindle actually *hdpi* but just is not working? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I make this work since the kindle is SO much larger in screen size?

Size is something that you measure in inches or millimeters. Density is measured in dots-per-inch (dpi).

Hence, it is entirely possible to have many devices, with widely varying screen *sizes*, all have the same screen *density*. Not only can a phone (e.g., LG G3) and a tablet (e.g., Kindle Fire) have the same density, but somebody could build a screen as large as a wall that also has the same density.

Having drawables (and mipmaps) at different densities means that when your app runs on devices with different densities, the drawables can appear to be roughly the same size, just with more detail on the higher-density screens. If you *also* want to have drawables for different screen sizes, you can, but you will need to have more directories and more versions of your artwork. For example, while `res/drawable-mdpi/` says "these resources are optimized for `mdpi` density", `res/drawable-w640dp-mdpi/` says "use these resources for devices whose current width is at least 4" (640dp), where these resources are optimized for `mdpi` density".

Comment: Thanks for the clarification that I probably already should of known but didn't in screen density. XD Also doesn't every one who wants to have Bitmaps perfectly in size have to optimize their image sizes with `res/drawable-w640dp-mdpi/`? Or is there another way to make the images be same percentage size for every device? For example have the background Bitmap image fit the full screen size for every device.

Comment: @PythonandAndroidforlife: I have no idea what you mean by "perfectly in size". Density will keep the images about the same physical size across screen densities. However, you may want larger images for larger screens, given that you have more screen space. "For example have the background Bitmap image fit the full screen size for every device" -- it will never fit the full screen size for every device, because there are many screen aspect ratios.

Comment: Is it possible to at least have the Bitmap background Image appear it is being a "background" Which means taking up the screen size. Also can you possibly give me link to read up on how this works.